# Getting values of an array from another view controller to View Controller in tableViews labels swift ios

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I am trying to get values from an array `tempArray` and `descArray` from `AddViewController` to a `ViewViewController` in a `tableview` in labels I want the both arrays values should be printed in `temLabel` and `descLabel` respectively but I am getting an error

> Index out of range
>   whitout any issue I don't know what to do I have researched but nothing found helpful.

Here is the code for ViewViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var getAddController : AddViewController = AddViewController()

@IBOutlet weak var menu: UIBarButtonItem!//
@IBOutlet weak var viewTableView: UITableView!


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let numberRows = getAddController.tempArray
    let numRow = String(describing: numberRows)
    print (numRow)
    return 10
    //numRow.count
    //getAddController.tempArray.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = viewTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ViewTableViewCell") as! ViewTableViewCell

    let temarrayNow = getAddController.tempArray
    let descArrayNow = getAddController.descArray

    let crrentTemarray = String(describing: temarrayNow)
    let decArNow = String(describing: descArrayNow)

    cell.titleLabel.text = crrentTemarray[indexPath.row]
    cell.descLabel.text = descArrayNow[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    menu.target = revealViewController()
    menu.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())


    viewTableView.delegate = self
    viewTableView.dataSource = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `numberOfRowsInSection` return the tempArray count not the fixed value 10.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let numberRows = getAddController.tempArray
    let numRow = String(describing: numberRows)
    print (numRow)
    return numberRows.count
    //numRow.count
    //getAddController.tempArray.count
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

In this method, you need to return array count not the static value

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let numberRows = getAddController.tempArray
    let numRow = String(describing: numberRows)
    print (numRow)
    return numberRows.count
}
```

And Note here that you are using two arrays **getAddController.tempArray** and **getAddController.descArray** in **cellForRowAt** and you are returning only one count in **numberOfRowsInSection** so you must have same no of elements in both array because if one of them is having less elements then you will get your error again

Answer (score 0):

i want to know weather tempArray and descArray, both have same number of element(arr.count)

and in cellForRowAt,

```
let crrentTemarray = String(describing: temarrayNow)
let decArNow = String(describing: descArrayNow)

cell.titleLabel.text = crrentTemarray[indexPath.row] //here you have used crrentTemarray

cell.descLabel.text = descArrayNow[indexPath.row]
```

**here you have used descArrayNow instead of decArNow** (if I am not wrong)

Comment: cell.descLabel.text = descArrayNow[indexPath.row], should be  descArNow[indexPath.row]